# Show that the flat connection is flat

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

Let $M$ be a manifold, let $L$ be the trivial line bundle over $M$.
Define a connection on $L$ by $\nabla:\Gamma(L)\rightarrow \Omega^1(L)$, by $\nabla_X(s)=ds(x)$.
Define the curvature $K(\nabla)$ of a connection by $K(\nabla)(X,Y)(s):=\nabla_X \nabla_Y(s)-\nabla_Y \nabla_X (s) - \nabla_{[X,Y]}(s)$.

> Show that for $\nabla_X(s)=ds(X)$, $F(\nabla)=0$.

If we use the equivalent definition of the curvature of $F(\nabla)=\nabla \circ \nabla$ it is easy to see that our connection is flat as $d\circ d=0$. But I want to know how to compute these concretely. Please tell me where I go wrong.

$$K(\nabla)(X,Y)(s):=\nabla_X \nabla_Y(s)-\nabla_Y \nabla_X (s) - \nabla_{[X,Y]}(s)$$
$$=d_X d_Y(s)-d_Y d_X (s) - d_{[X,Y]}(s)$$
$$=d_X ds(Y)-d_Y ds(X) - ds({[X,Y]})$$
I am unsure about this step. $ds$ is a one-from so it takes in vectors and returns scalars. Or alternatively it takes in a vector field and returns a smooth function. So $ds(X)$ is a smooth function. Since $d_X$ acts on smooth functions we have.
$$=d(ds(Y)) X-d(ds(X))(Y) - ds({[X,Y]})$$

I think for some reason we can chance some brackets around and say $d(ds(Y)) X=d ds(Y)(X)=0$ as $d\circ d=0$.

$$=- ds({[X,Y]})$$
I don't think this is true but it looks like the only thing left to do
$$=- ds(XY-YX)$$

$$=- ds(XY)+ds(YX)$$

I'm sure what I've done is incorrect in some way. If you could tell me how that would be helpful.

Comment: I think you mean $\nabla_Xs = ds(X)$. What do you mean by $d_X$, $d_Y$?

Comment: Sorry yes I do mean $\nabla_X s= ds(X)$. By $d_X$ i mean $\nabla_X$, so $d_X(s)=ds(X)$. This does not seem to be great notation but I thought I've seen this done like this

Comment: Your claim that $d(ds(X))(Y) = d(ds(Y))(X)$ is false. To get the correct answer, you need to use the fact that $ds(X) = Xs$ (here $X$ is viewed as a derivation of smooth functions).

Comment: Be careful: $"XY"$ is not defined (this is not a vector field), and the notation $[X,Y] = XY - YX$ is to be understood as the composition of derivations, that is if $f$ is a function, $[X,Y]\cdot f = X\cdot(Y\cdot f) - Y\cdot (X\cdot f)$, which is a well defined function.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese could you extend this comment please? I am not sure how to calculate $d(Xs)(Y)$

Comment: Well, $Xs$ is another function, so $d(Xs)(Y) = Y(Xs)$.

Comment: Then this gives that over all that we have $F(\nabla)= Y(Xs)-X(Ys)-[X,Y](s)$. Then we have $[X,Y](s)=Y(Xs)-X(Ys)$ and we are done.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.